# Change size or set width of button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the width of the button as below, but it isn't changing the size. Can someone please advise on how the size can be changed within this JavaScript?

```js
var tableElement = document.getElementById('dynamic_field_arrow_deliverables');
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
var t = document.createTextNode("->");
btn.setAttribute("width", "250px");
btn.appendChild(t); 
btn.id ='btnDeliver'+i;
tr.appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the css `width` property.

```js
var tableElement = document.getElementById('dynamic_field_arrow_deliverables');
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
var t = document.createTextNode("->");
btn.style.width = "250px";
btn.appendChild(t);
btn.id ='btnDeliver1';
tableElement.appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<div id="dynamic_field_arrow_deliverables"></div>
```